# Create a sql sequence programmatically in Java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I need to create a sql sequence in sql server programmatically from Java and I should be able to retrieve the continuous value from the sequence to program. First of all can I do so? If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible as all SQL servers provide some functionality and guarantee ACID rules. Even with very simple old MySql engine which didn't support transactions it's achievable. The easiest and widely supported approach is:

```
 CREATE TABLE SequenceValue (
     sequenceIdentifier varchar(124) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     sequenceValue INT NOT NULL;
 );
```

All you need to do in the program is:

```
Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
try {
    con.setAutoCommit(true);
    PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT sequenceValue  SequenceValue WHERE sequenceIdentifier = ?");
    st.setString(1, sequenceIdentifier);
    SQLException retried = null;
    for (;;) {
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
        if (!rs.next()) {
            if (retried != null)
                throw retried;
            PreparedStatement ins = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO SequenceValue (sequenceIdentifier, sequenceValue) VALUES (?, ?)");
            ins.setString(1, sequenceIdentifier);
            ins.setLong(2, 0);
            try {
                ins.executeUpdate();
            }
            catch (SQLException ex) {
                // store the exception and rethrow if next query retry fails
                retried = ex;
            }
        }
        else {
            long value = rs.getLong(1);
            PreparedStatement upd = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE SequenceValue SET sequenceValue = sequenceValue+1 WHERE sequenceIdentifier = ? AND sequenceValue = ?");
            upd.setString(1, sequenceIdentifier);
            upd.setLong(2, value+1);
            if (upd.executeUpdate() == 1)                
                return value+1;
        }
    }
}
finally {
    con.close();
}
```

Briefly: The code avoid transactions completely. At the beginning it tries to retrieve the sequence value according to identifier. In case it's not found, it attempts to create it and retries retrieving again. It doesn't fail in case the value was created in the meantime.

If the value is found, it tries to increment it using atomic update on the row. If it succeeds then it returns the incremented value, if not it retries again.